# using components of shared module in the others module for angular 4

Tags: angular

this is the structure of my project, I have a common component named StarComponent is in sharedModule. How can I use StarComponent in ClientListComponent.

needless to say, I have added StarComponent to export and declaration array in sharedModule and import sharedModule in (app.module or adminModule or clinetModule ) none of them works!

```
---app
------app.module.ts
------sharedModule
------------------StarComponent
------adminModule
-----------------clinetModule
-----------------------------ClientListComponent
```

***updated:***

I have prepared an example to show It does not work

demo :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aceiz9

Comment: show that code so we can get more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have

```
//shared.module.ts
@NgModule({
    imports:[],
    declarations: [StartComponent],
    exports: [StartComponent]
})
export class SharedModule { }

//appmodule.ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    AdminModule,
    ....
  ],
  providers: [
    ....
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

//You can use StartComponent in your ClientListComponent

//ClientListComponent.ts
import { StartComponent } from '../../../sharedModule/StartComponent.ts;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <app-client-list></app-client-list>
    `
})
```

Comment: hi, thank you! but It does not work! you can test for sample project!

Comment: I'm pretty sure its working because if you type random garbage into star.component.ts, it throws errors. Where is the star component actually used?? I looked at all your routes and individual components and it doesnt seem like you've included the selector in any templates or route paths

Comment: JK - i see it now,  it was commented out